# Coil gun design

Tags: batteries, capacitor, resistors, sensor, coil

I've been doing a bunch of research on coil gun schematics and watching a ton of videos, and in almost every schematic and video they have some kind of photo or IR sensor to detect when the projectile passes a certain phase in the coils.

I was wondering if there was a way to time the discharges of the capacitors instead of compromising the integrity of the barrel. The idea seems simple in concept but the more I look into it the more I end up getting confused. If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So all you need to know are the initial speed, distance, acceleration, final speed and you can work out distance travelled - may need air temperature, viscosity and other friction factors as well, that will give you your calculated distance travelled to compare to the actual distance. Then trigger subsequent stages as needed. For an example check out The Core where they restart the Earth's core rotation.

Comment: thank you, that's excellent information, Once I have those figures though I need to know how to initiate that reaction ( for instance if it takes 0.1 second for my projectile to exit one of the coils) how to then shut that coil off and activate my second coil for that 0.1 second.

Comment: Control 2 switches with timers…

Comment: Sensors sound MUCH easier. However, you could try:  Power first coil only with different on/off timings. (FET or bipolar transistor as switch. Obtain optimum result. Then add second coil power with first set as above and adjust to optimum result. THEN see how  hanging first affects overall result. Add a few mmore this way. Adjust temperature and humidity to swee how much it affects resultrs --> Use sensors (probably ) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do it by dead reckoning. It's certainly easier to get going when you are starting out, and I would recommend you start that way.

The disadvantage is that it's tuned to one size of projectile. It depends on all the other parameters, like barrel friction, how the projectile bounces off the sides as it accelerates, and 101 other things, being repeatable run to run. This becomes rapidly more of a problem when you try to add further stages.

Even if you really want the high performance big thing, you will always learn something you didn't expect by building something small and simple first, I always do. And if the small and simple thing meets your requirements, then you've saved some time and effort.